# How do I modify part of a column in a Spark data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr, dplyr

I am trying to modify part of a column from a Spark data frame. The row selection is based on the vector (in R env) `ID.X`. The replacement is another vector (in R env) `Role`.
I have tried the following:

```
> sdf.bigset %>% filter(`_id` %in% ID.X) %>% 
  mutate(data_role= Role )
```

It crashes my R

And the following

```
> head(DT.XSamples)
                        _id   Role 
1: 5996e9e12a2aa6315127ed0e  Training                 
2: 5996e9e12a2aa6315127ed0f  Training                  
3: 5996e9e12a2aa6315127ed10  Training  

> setkey(DT.XSamples,`_id`)

> Lookup.XyDaRo <- function(x){
  unlist(DT.XSamples[x,Role])
}

> sdf.bigset %>% filter(`_id` %in% ID.X) %>% rowwise()%>%
  mutate(data_role= Lookup.XyDaRo(`_id`) )
```

As well as the following

```
> Fn.lookup.XyDaRo <- function(id,role){
  ifelse(is.na(role), unlist(DT.XSamples[id,Role] ),  role )
}

> sdf.bigset%>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(data_role= Fn.lookup.XyDaRo(`_id`,data_role))
```

Then I get for both cases

```
Error: is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE
```

`sdf.bigset` is a Spark data frame.
`DT.XSamples` is a data table living in R.

Any idea what I am doing wrong, or how it should be properly done?

Comment: The error could be that your dataset is `data.table`  Could you try by converting to `tibble` or data.frame i..e `setDF(sdf.bigset)`

Comment: `sdf.bigset` is a Spark data frame. It is too big to live in a local R environment unfortunately. I am guessing turning `DT.XSamples` to tibble shouldn't help, since the function `Lookup.XyDaRo` output is unlisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `sdf.bigset` looks like this:

```
sdf.bigset <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(`id` = 1:10, data_role = "Unknown"))
```

adn `DT.XSamples` is defined as:

```
XSamples <- data.frame(
  `id` = c(3, 5, 9), role = c("Training", "Dev", "Secret")
)
```

Convert `DT.XSamples` to Spark:

```
sdf.XSamples <- copy_to(sc, XSamples)
```

`left_join` and `coalesce`:

```
left_join(sdf.bigset, sdf.XSamples, by="id") %>% 
  mutate(data_role = coalesce(role, data_role))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
      id data_role role    
   <int> <chr>     <chr>   
 1     1 Unknown   NA      
 2     2 Unknown   NA      
 3     3 Training  Training
 4     4 Unknown   NA      
 5     5 Dev       Dev     
 6     6 Unknown   NA      
 7     7 Unknown   NA      
 8     8 Unknown   NA      
 9     9 Secret    Secret  
10    10 Unknown   NA
```

Finally drop role with negative `select`.

Regarding your code:

- Vector replacements won't work because Spark `DataFrame` is more relation (in relational algebra sense) not `DataFrame`, and in general order is not defined, therefore operations like this are not implemented.
- DT variant won't work because you cannot execute plain R code, with exception to (incredibly inefficient) `spark_apply`.

Comment: Thanks for the strategy to the solution, and the explanation why it didn't work for me.